# Keyword Metadata is not coming properly if it has tcm id of some other componnets

Tags: content-delivery, keyword

We have a Business requirement where they want to Attach some Images in some keywords using keyword metadata schema.

i am able to fetch Metadata Information, but it seems it is not working for the keywords which has image tcm added in metadata .

here is the keyword snapshot :

[image]

i am using below code to fetch the metdata :

```
    if (keywordMeta != null)
                    {
                        List<string> notifications = new List<string>();
                        IDictionary metaNameDictionary = keywordMeta.NameValues;
                        IEnumerator metaNameEnumerator = metaNameDictionary.GetEnumerator();
                        if (metaNameEnumerator != null)
                        {
                            while (metaNameEnumerator.MoveNext())
                            {
                                DictionaryEntry de = (DictionaryEntry)metaNameEnumerator.Current;
                                NameValuePair currentMeta = (NameValuePair)de.Value;
                                if (currentMeta != null)
                                {
                                    using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(@"C:\Temp\log.txt"))
                                    {


                                    switch (currentMeta.Name.ToLower())
                                    {
                                        case "title":
                                            syllabusMeta.Title = currentMeta.Value.ToString();
                                            break;

                                        case "sub_title":
                                            syllabusMeta.Sub_Title = currentMeta.Value.ToString();
                                            break;

                                        case "description":
                                             Log($"description is {currentMeta.Value.ToString()}", w);
                                            syllabusMeta.Description = WebUtility.HtmlEncode(currentMeta.Value.ToString());
                                            break;
}
    }
```

But i do not get tcm id in src in logs :

```
Log Entry : 11:57:07 18 July 2019
  :
  :description is <p>Sample Description testing</p>
<img></img>
```

if i use a image path in src then it works fine , i get the full image src tags from metadata. so src with tcm does not comes but src with some string comes in metadata. So below is valid and works

[image]

is they any way to fetch tcm id's which are configured in metadata?